# why the header file needs to be included in the definition file?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm new to C, just a question on the header file, below is the code that uses the header file as recommended:

```
//test.h

extern int globalVariable;
```

```
//test.c

#include "test.h"

int globalVariable = 2020;
```

```
//main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h" 

int main()
{
   printf("Value is %d", globalVariable);
}
```

I don't understand that why we need to put `#include "test.h"` in `test.c` file, what's the benefit of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually doesn't, but it's a good practice.

If you wrote:

```
double globalVariable = 2020;
```

you would have undefined behavior. Now if you wrote

```
#include "test.h"
double globalVariable = 2020;
```

the compiler will catch your mistake. Since the same definition is available to all modules that use `globalVariable` by including the same header file, such a mistake is much less likely.

Comment: but doesn't it defeat the purpose of extern?

Comment: @Nish: No. `extern` goes in the header file. The actual declaration doesn't have it.

Comment: but when compiling test.c it will have globalVariable  definition as well as extern declaration. Isn't it?

Comment: @Nish: Try writing `extern int globalVariable; extern int globalVariable; int globalVariable;` It's fine.

Comment: @Joshua could you also have a look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570702/reinitialize-a-global-variable-that-is-already-defined-in-other-source-file