# reinitialize a global variable that is already defined in other source file

Tags: c, gcc

I'm new to C, just a question on global variable, below is the code that uses the header file as recommended:

```
//test.h

extern int globalVariable;
```

```
//test.c

#include "test.h"

int globalVariable = 2020;
```

```
//main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h" 

int main()
{
   printf("Value is %d", globalVariable);
}
```

so it works well and the print output is 2020.

But if I change the `main.c` as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h" 

int globalVariable;

int main()
{
   printf("Value is %d", globalVariable);
}
```

it still compile and the output is still 2020. Below is my question:

Q1-When I add `int globalVariable;` in main.c, isn't that it re-initialize the globalVariable to 0 becuase `int globalVariable;` is the same as `int globalVariable = 0;`. So why the output is still 2020 rather than 0?

Q2-`globalVariable` is already defined in `test.c`, and I re-define(reinitialize) it to 0, should it be a compile error since C doesn't allow multiple definition, so why the program still compile?

Comment: If your program does not conform to the standard then you should not assume that the standard defines its behavior.  Nor the behavior of any particular implementation when translating the program's code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration at file scope:

```
int globalVariable;
```

Is a **tentative definition**.  It has no initializer and is not `static`.  GCC can "fold" tentative definitions together from multiple translation units into a single identifier.  This is not specified by the standard but is an extension supported by GCC.

In this case the tentative definition in main.c gets rolled into the the complete definition in test.c and initialized with the given value.  If you were to use an initializer in main.c as well, then you would get a multiple definition error.

Comment: Incidentally I've heard this is standard C++ and lots of debates on whether it's standard C or not.

Comment: @dbush so `int globalVariable;` doesn't initialize it to 0?if thats the case, why when I print it its value is 0?

Comment: @slowjams It *would* initialize it to 0 if there was no other definition that does initialize it.  But because you have `int globalVariable = 2020;` in test.c, that's the one that takes effect and the tentative definition in main.c becomes essentially a declaration.